# What's the Python code or function to find the average score when you don't use integers?

Tags: python

So i'm trying to make an IQ test program using Python 3.3 and so far i have 5 questions done. However, i don't know how to average the score because their answers are going to be strings and integers. i don't know how to calculate the average if they get some questions right or wrong.

back to my question, how do i average correct and incorrect question scores?

i took a small picture of it here : http://prntscr.com/2eifeh

Comment: Why don't you paste the code here instead?

Comment: You don't store the results of the answers.  How can you take the average of undefined?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a variable to store the correct and the incorrect answers. Each time the user gets a correct answer, add 1 to the corresponding variable. Do the same with the incorrect answers.

```
correct = 0
incorrect = 0

...
if question1 == "johnny":
    print("Correct !")
    correct += 1
elif ...:
    ...
    correct += 1
else:
    print(...)
    incorrect += 1
...
```

I don't know if by "average", you mean percentage or something else. You could do it with:

```
print( "% of correct answers: ", correct*100.0/(correct+incorrect) )
```